# How to correctly avoid specific TableViewCells of beeing editable?

Tags: java, properties, javafx, tableview, editingstate

Following Issue: I need to know at specific moments, weather my [TableView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) is currently beeing edited or not. I used the [editingCellProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#editingCellProperty) and binded a specific businesslogic to it, to get informed, whenever the table switches these modes.

Unfortunalty the state is not always shown correctly, because I have specific cells (within the same column) which are not supposed to be edited at all, but still when clicked on a noneditable cell a TablePosition is set into the editingCellProperty, hence I get the information, that my TableView is editing, eventhough per condition its been told, that this cell is not editable and the edit mode never really starts.

I created a small example, where all even rows of ColumnName are editable, while odd rows are not.

[image: Small Example]

Example-Code:

```
public class TableViewEditableStateError extends Application
{
  public static void main( final String[] args )
  {
    launch( args );
  }

  @Override
  public void start( final Stage primaryStage )
  {
    Item item1 = new Item( 1, "Item1" );
    Item item2 = new Item( 2, "Item2" );
    Item item3 = new Item( 3, "Item3" );
    Item item4 = new Item( 4, "Item4" );

    ObservableList<Item> itemList = FXCollections.observableArrayList( item1, item2, item3, item4 );

    TableColumn<Item, Integer> columnId = new TableColumn<>( "ColumnId" );
    TableColumn<Item, String> columnName = new TableColumn<>( "ColumnName" );

    columnId.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Item, Integer>( "id" ) );
    columnName.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>( "name" ) );

    //    columnName.setCellFactory( TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn() ); -> Using own implementation for editablestate-behaviour

    columnName.setCellFactory( new Callback<TableColumn<Item, String>, TableCell<Item, String>>()
    {
      @Override
      public TableCell<Item, String> call( final TableColumn<Item, String> column )
      {
        TableCell<Item, String> cell = new EditableTableCell<Item>()
        {
          @Override
          public void startEdit()//Business-Rule to deceide, which cell is editable.
          {
            if ( getTableRow().getIndex() % 2 != 0/* Only Odd Values are editable. -> Any Random Condition */)
            {
              System.out.println( "Do not initiate Editing." );
              return;
            }

            System.out.println( "initiate Editing." );
            super.startEdit();
          }
        };

        return cell;
      }
    } );

    columnName.setOnEditCommit( new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Item, String>>()
    {
      @Override
      public void handle( final CellEditEvent<Item, String> event )
      {
        final Item item = event.getRowValue();

        System.out.println( "Change Item " + item + " from " + event.getOldValue() + " to new value "
            + event.getNewValue() );

        item.setName( event.getNewValue() );
      }
    } );

    final TableView<Item> tableView = new TableView<>( itemList );
    tableView.getColumns().add( columnId );
    tableView.getColumns().add( columnName );

    tableView.setColumnResizePolicy( TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY );

    tableView.setEditable( true );
    columnId.setEditable( false );

    Label label = new Label( "Editing-State: is not editing..." );

    //Listener to record editing behaviour:
    tableView.editingCellProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<TablePosition<Item, ?>>()
    {
      @Override
      public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends TablePosition<Item, ?>> observable,
                           final TablePosition<Item, ?> oldValue, final TablePosition<Item, ?> newValue )
      {
        System.out.println( "Editstate changed to: " + newValue );

        if ( newValue != null )
          label.setText( "Editing-State: is editing..." );
        else
          label.setText( "Editing-State: is not editing..." );
      }
    } );

    BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();
    layout.setCenter( tableView );
    layout.setTop( label );
    Scene scene = new Scene( layout, 400, 400 );
    scene.getStylesheets().add( getClass().getResource( "application.css" ).toExternalForm() );
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  class EditableTableCell<S> extends TableCell<S, String>
  {
    protected TextField textField;

    @Override
    public void startEdit()
    {
      super.startEdit();

      if ( textField == null )
      {
        createTextField();
      }

      setGraphic( textField );
      setContentDisplay( ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY );
      Platform.runLater( new Runnable()
      {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          textField.selectAll();
          textField.requestFocus();
        }
      } );
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelEdit()
    {
      super.cancelEdit();
      setText( getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString() );
      setContentDisplay( ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY );
      textField = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem( final String item, final boolean empty )
    {
      super.updateItem( item, empty );
      if ( empty )
      {
        setText( null );
        setGraphic( null );
      }
      else
      {
        if ( isEditing() )
        {
          if ( textField != null )
          {
            textField.setText( getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString() );
          }
          setGraphic( textField );
          setContentDisplay( ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY );
        }
        else
        {
          setText( getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString() );
          setContentDisplay( ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY );
        }
      }
    }

    private void createTextField()
    {
      textField = new TextField( getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString() );

      textField.setOnKeyPressed( new EventHandler<KeyEvent>()
      {
        @Override
        public void handle( final KeyEvent keyEvent )
        {
          if ( keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER )
          {
            commitEdit( textField.getText() );
          }
          else if ( keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE )
          {
            cancelEdit();
          }
        }
      } );

      textField.focusedProperty().addListener( new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
      {
        @Override
        public void changed( final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, final Boolean oldValue,
                             final Boolean newValue )
        {
          if ( !newValue && textField != null )
          {
            final String text = textField.getText();
            commitEdit( text );
          }
        }
      } );
    }
  }
}
```

DataClass Item:

```
public class Item
{
  private final IntegerProperty id   = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
  private final StringProperty  name = new SimpleStringProperty();

  public Item( final int id, final String name )
  {
    this.id.set( id );
    this.name.set( name );
  }

  public int getId()
  {
    return id.get();
  }

  public String getName()
  {
    return name.get();
  }

  public void setId( final int id )
  {
    this.id.set( id );
  }

  public void setName( final String name )
  {
    this.name.set( name );
  }

  public IntegerProperty idProperty()
  {
    return id;
  }

  public StringProperty nameProperty()
  {
    return name;
  }
}
```

I narrowed my problem down to the [editCell](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#edit%28int,%20javafx.scene.control.TableColumn%29) Method of TableView, since it is not reacting on cell-specific editable-states:

```
/**
 * Causes the cell at the given row/column view indexes to switch into
 * its editing state, if it is not already in it, and assuming that the 
 * TableView and column are also editable.
 */
public void edit(int row, TableColumn<S,?> column) {
    if (!isEditable() || (column != null && ! column.isEditable())) {
        return;
    }

    if (row < 0 && column == null) {
        setEditingCell(null);
    } else {
        setEditingCell(new TablePosition<>(this, row, column));
    }
}
```

But since setEditingCell() is a private method, I can´t override the edit-Method the way I want it to work. So I am curious: **Can anyone tell me the correct way to implement dynamic editable table cells within the same column, while the editingCell-State of TableView will always stay correct?**

Comment: I guess you could just follow your logic in the change listener.  I do something similar to you to block editing, but I don't need to listen.  You can access the item from the TablePosition if you need to.

Comment: That´s what I would like to do, but the only problem is, that the changelistener method also gets invoked with corresponding tableposition (instead of null), even when I click on a non editable cell, because the TableViews edit Method does not know about my non editable cells within the column (in my example every second row). Have you checked the property, while blocking editing in your case? I´m curious how you implemented the blocking aspect without letting the edit method changing the property.

Comment: It looks like you don't use your EditableCell class in this example, but that's where I check. Right at '@Override public void startEdit(){ if (!MyCondition) return; }` .  However, I added your listener and it still fires.

Comment: You said "the only problem is, that the changelistener method also gets invoked with corresponding tableposition (instead of null), even when I click on a non editable cell".  What I mean is to check in your listener again for the business logic condition and handle it appropriately.

Comment: @brian First of all thanks for your effort in trying to help me out here. I use the EditableCell within the CellFactory. It only creates instances of EditableCells. If you like, you can try the example, its a fully working one. It might gets clearer in what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Its not all about the label pointing out the right state of the table, this was just an example. Of course rechecking my condition within the listener would solve it, you are right, but I dislike, that the editingCellProperty propagates a wrong state to all its listeners. Others could subscribe for this property as well, and they are trusting this property to be correct, but I can´t make sure, that they will always get the right state then.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in the listener to just ignore editing cell changes you don't want

```
    editingCellProperty().addListener((obs,ov,nv) -> {
        if (nv!=null && nv.getRow() % 2 != 0/* Only Odd Values are editable. -> Any Random Condition */)
        {
          System.out.println( "Pretend this never happened" );
        }
        else
        System.out.println("Editstate changed to: " + nv);
    });
```

Even if I `setEditable(false)` for some cells in the EditableCell constructor, the listener still fires.  It don't think it happens in the TableCell edit method because there it checks for `!isEditable()` .  What is happening is the editingCell changes, from the last cell that was being edited to the new cell that's not being edited.  I guess that makes a bit of sense, however you don't get a null, but the TablePosition of the cell not being edited.  Even if no cell is being edited, trying to edit a non-editable cell still fires the listener.

I think this needs a bug report.